# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI?

Tags: spring-mvc, web.xml, dispatcher

Hi I have the following code:
Controller:

@Controller

```
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
        public ModelAndView HelloWorld() {
            String message = "My First SpringMVC Program ";
            return new ModelAndView("hello","message",message);
        }
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
            <!-- load on startup is used to determine the order of initializing the servlet when the application
            server starts up. The lower the number, earlier it starts -->
            <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan 
base-package="org.example.controller"/>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView">
</property>
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/">
</property>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
```

When I run this code, I get the following warning
"WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringDemo/Hello.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'". What wrong am I doing?

Comment: finally I got it fixed myself. some issue with eclipse and navigation!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `web.xml` says all requests with url pattern `*.html` are forwarded to Spring. Your `@RequestMapping` only filters on `/hello`, but the request url reaching Spring is `/hello.html`. What you are missing is the `.html`. Your `@RequestMapping` should be `/hello.html`.

After your request goes through your controller you are forwarding to a view named `hello`, and the configuration in your `spring-servlet.xml` resolves this to `hello.jsp` in `WEB-INF/jsp`, so make sure you have that as well.

Happy coding!

Comment: oops I saw your answer just now. Thank you very much.

Comment: but i did the same but it made no success :( previously my code was running fine in another application with adding .html but in this it is still not working :( - any idea?