# Spring-MVC: No mapping found for HTTP request

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to access views without controller in Spring. I followed these links [1](http://spring.io/blog/2009/12/21/mvc-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/),[2](http://codyburleson.com/2013/07/20/mapping-to-a-view-in-spring-with-no-controller/) but the code returns following error.

```
 WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myproject/WEB-
 INF/jsp/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'test'
```

I checked answer of these questions but none of them was useful [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192061/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27419037/org-springframework-web-servlet-dispatcherservlet-nohandlerfound-no-mapping-fou),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910482/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri).

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/test-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file></welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

**test-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Forwards requests to the "/" resource to the "index" view -->
    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index" />
    <!-- <mvc:view-controller path="/index" view-name="index" /> -->

</beans>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Started from Here -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your servlet-mapping to following:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Asterisks is removed.